# mappls.direction is not a function i'm getting this error

Tags: javascript, mapmyindia-api

i'm getting this error in mappls.direction is not function

[image]

I'm getting this error in web

1. mappls.direction is not function
2. Please check credentials invalid

even i'm using his default code (https://about.mappls.com/api/web-sdk/vector-plugin-example/Direction/mappls-tracking-direction-plugin)

Answer (score 0):

First You have to Register from this [link](https://apis.mappls.com/console)

You can get client Id and secret from [console](https://apis.mappls.com/console/#/app/project/project-details?)

to generate access_token from here
[Generate Token](https://www.mapmyindia.com/api/advanced-maps/doc/authentication-api.php#/Token%20Generation%20API/tokenGenerationAPI)

and than put in your code

```
<script src="https://apis.mappls.com/advancedmaps/api/<Token>/map_sdk?layer=vector&v=3.0&callback=initMap1"></script>
<script src="https://apis.mappls.com/advancedmaps/api/<token>/map_sdk_plugins?v=3.0"></script>
```